# Differences between "das", "es", and "dieses"

Tags: standard-german

How do *das*, *es*, and *dieses* differ when refering to different things? When would you use each? (Please ignore, for the moment, the differences between gender, and the fact that I’ve left *things* intentionally ill-defined!)

Comment: They mean "the", "it", and "this" -- what is unclear about the difference? Can you please [edit] your question to clarify what you are asking? As is, I'd say your question is off-topic since you could answer it with a dictionary.

Comment: @Robert If the question is carefully read, one can register that Aaron is asking for the meanings of these words when they are used as references. So, your hint, that _das_ would mean _the_ is plainly wrong. This also undermines your argument that the question could be easily solved by looking the words up in a dictionary.

Comment: The question would definitely be easier to answer if some examples were added.

Comment: @DavidVogt I think the question is pretty clear. I tried to answer based on how I understood it. I think, we should be more careful when downvoting and closing questions from new contributors to the site. Honestly, I do not consider this behavior very constructive. I think it is a fair and understandable question and it cannot easily be solved by looking the words up in a dictionary. It would require a grammar book at least. It is also a rather interesting and complex question and might be of interest to later visitors of the site. So I think, it is neither off-topic nor worth downvoting it.

Comment: And I think that it is part of the problem of the questioner that they can't make examples. But the answering community should be able to gather examples and demonstrate rules on the basis of them. I think, this is exactly what this site is meant to be about.

Answer (score 2):

- **das**: is the article of a noun and thus needed and used the moment you use the noun it is linked to. e.g.: *"Das Haus ist schön."*
- **dieses**: is a reference to an object in an earlier [part of a] sentence. That implies: without the reference noone knows what is meant. e.g.: *"Dieses kann man mieten."* - only make sense if it follows it reference *"Das Haus ist schön. Dieses kann man mieten."*

  - Use to make a "personal distance": *"Dieses Ding da ist grün."* -  *"dieses"* is used as an article. In case there is no earlier spoken/ written reference, it is necessary to have somehow pointed (fingers, eyes etc.) to the object that the receiver gets the reference. You could also said *"Das Ding da ist grün."* Using *"dieses"* in combination with *"Ding"* includes a evaluation of *"Ding"* as something suspicious or negative.
  - Use to include a direction: *"Dieses Haus da ist schön."* Here is a reference, just rather not to the noun *"Haus"*, there is a location implied. Like while talking I point somewhere (to the "Haus").
- **es**: most unspecific reference. Can reference to anything from something specific like *"Das Haus ist schön. Es sieht echt toll aus."* (like *"dieses"*) to the most vague circumstances *"Es ist halt so."* The more vague, the less anyone writes/ speaks the reference - the implication is, that any reader/ listener knows it. Said that, there is no guaranty that the ones that uses *"Es ist halt so."* has an exact/ clear idea what *"es"* means.

Answer (score 2):

All three words are referring to an object which has neuter grammatical gender. The differences are as follows:

**es** has two different use cases:

1. It simply refers to any object which has neuter gender. Most often it translates perfectly to *it* in english:

> Siehst du das rote Auto? Ich liebe es.
>
> You see the red car? I love it.

2. There is another important use of *es*, the [expletive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_expletive) *es*: Here *es* works as a subject which is required by the verb. *it* in english has the very same function:

> Es regnet.
>
> *It is raining.*

**dieses** is the opposite of *jenes*: *dieses* is referring to an object which is (in some sense) close to the speaker, while *jenes* is referring_ to an object which is (in some sense) distant to the speaker:

> Dieses Auto (hier vorn) gefällt mir besser als jenes (dort hinten).
>
> *I prefer this car (here) over that one (over there).*

This notion of proximity vs. distance can also refer to the time in speech when the referent has been addressed. In this cases *dieses* refers to the object addressed lastly, while *jenes* refers to an object which had been adressed earlier:

> Franz behauptete, dass alle Menschen sterblich seien und dass alle Menschen gleich seien. Diesem [dass alle Menschen gleich sind] muss ich zwar widersprechen, aber jenem [dass alle Menschen sterblich sind] kann ich zustimmen.

This would translate to something like:

> *Franz claimed, that alle men were mortal and also all men were equal. While I have to oppose the latter, I do agree with the former.*

**das** is somewhat between *dieses* and *es*. It also has multiple usecases:

1. It refers to an entity, which is somehow differentiated from something else (in that sense, it differs from *es*), but not in a sense of proximity or distance (in that sense it differs from *dieses*).

1a) This differentiation might often be constituted by deictic gestures, so in spoken language you will very often find a construction *das ... das* replacing *dieses ... jenes*, where the speaker is just pointing at the things while referring to each by *das*.

1b) Besides that, the differentiation which *das* refers to, can and will often be implicit:

> Das mag ich an dir.

which would translate into:

> *I like that about you.*

This might implicitly focus on the fact that there might be things which I don't like about you. That's why in this cases, *das* bears a stronger emphasis than *it*.

2) *das* also refers to logical entities, to the meanings of a subclause. This is a difference to *it* which only refers to physical objects (as long as it is not used as an expletive):

> Du bist sehr witzig. Das gefällt mir.

This example would translate to english something like:

> *You are very funny. I like that.*

While in english it might be correct to use *that*, the german sentence

> Du bist sehr witzig. Dieses gefällt mir.

would be wrong, since there is no differentiation based on proximity here.

Also

> Du bist sehr witzig. Es gefällt mir.

would be wrong, since the reference is not referring to a physical object. Generally, everything reffered to by *das* in this situation can be expressed by a subclause with *dass*:

But take care that a subclause with an expletive *es* would be correct:

> Es gefällt mir an dir, dass du sehr witzig bist.
>
> I like [it] that you are very funny.

Comment: Thanks for your more detailed answer, covers more aspects. I think, the usage of _dieses_ in combination with _jenes / geographical proximity_ is a too narrow approach. Like I claimed/ stated, in combination with _Ding_ it might be close in geographical meaning - and it is far in emotional binding/ liking to me.